# importError: cannot import name 'model_builder' from 'object_detection.builders' (unknown location)

Tags: python, tensorflow, importerror

i got an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/User/Documents/Projects/Tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/builders/model_builder_tf2_test.py", line 24, in <module>
    from object_detection.builders import model_builder
ImportError: cannot import name 'model_builder' from 'object_detection.builders' (unknown location)
```

there is **init** in my folder
i was running model_builder_tf2_test.py via cmd and this error happen

the file script

```
import unittest

import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf

from google.protobuf import text_format
from object_detection.builders import model_builder
from object_detection.builders import model_builder_test
from object_detection.core import losses
from object_detection.models import center_net_resnet_feature_extractor
from object_detection.protos import center_net_pb2
from object_detection.protos import model_pb2
from object_detection.utils import tf_version
```

Comment: try putting `import sys; sys.path.append('c:/Users/User/Documents/Projects/Tensorflow/models/research')` at the beginning of the script

Comment: @NicolasGervais its work but is there another way without sys.path.append()?

Comment: In the documentation they use Linux and add this location to `PATH`. You can do it with Windows too, but I would advise against it. If you make another project they will always point to the same folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This location needs to be in `PATH` so try this:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('path/to/Tensorflow/models/research')
```